# How to custom MTP/PTP device icon?

Tags: android, window, usb, mtp

when the device in MTP mode,the device icon is a portable device.

when the device in PTP mode,th  device icon is a camera type device.

Now,I want to change the device icon when the device is pluged into pc.

How to custom MTP/DEVICE device icon?

Thanks very much